# Jquery Ajaxq error - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery

I am getting this error while trying to run an ajaxq call. I am successfully running similar calls within the same web page. I am also able to successfully complete my call if I switch my function to a ajax call instead of ajaxq. Here's some code.

```
function LoadAbsBetaGroupNotionalChart() {
        $.ajaxq("GetGrid", {
            url: 'AnyChartXmlGenerator.aspx?bid=' + myQueryStrings['bid'] + "&charttype=betagroupnotional&charttitle=&indexCode=" + myQueryStrings['indexCode'] + "&jon=" + myQueryStrings['jon'] + "&sam=" + myQueryStrings['sam'],
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var absBetaGroupNotionalChart = new AnyChart('./swf/AnyChart.swf');
                absBetaGroupNotionalChart.width = '300';
                absBetaGroupNotionalChart.height = '280';
                absBetaGroupNotionalChart.setData = data;
                //absBetaGroupNotionalChart.setXMLFile('AnyChartXmlGenerator.aspx?bid=' + myQueryStrings['bid'] + "&charttype=betagroupnotional&charttitle=&indexCode=" + myQueryStrings['indexCode'] + "&jon=" + myQueryStrings['jon'] + "&sam=" + myQueryStrings['sam']);
                absBetaGroupNotionalChart.addEventListener("draw", function () {
                    saveChartAsImage(absBetaGroupNotionalChart, randomDirName, "absBetaGroupNotionalChart");
                });
                absBetaGroupNotionalChart.write('absBetaGroupNotionalChart');
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I know what it is you cannot make an ajaxq call within another ajaxq call, even if you change the name of the ajaxq. I replaced my call with ajax instead of ajaxq and it worked.